# How to call an array outside of a function in SketchUp Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sketchup

I am building a custom Decimal Degrees (DD) to Decimal Minute Seconds (DMS) function to use in SketchUp's Ruby. Below is my script.

```
arg1 = 45.525123

def DMS(arg1)
    angle = arg1
    deg = angle.truncate()
    dec = (angle - angle.truncate()).round(6)
    totalsecs = (dec * 3600).round(6)
    mins = (totalsecs / 60).truncate()
    secs = (((totalsecs / 60) - (totalsecs / 60).truncate()) * 60).round(2)
    array = [deg, mins, secs]
end

DMS(arg1)
```

So far so good, if you ran this script in Ruby, you'd probably end up with an array that gives you
[45, 31, 30.44]

I then try to add a line of code which assigns that array under a different name. Here is the new code with the extra line.

```
arg1 = 45.525123

def DMS(arg1)
    angle = arg1
    deg = angle.truncate()
    dec = (angle - angle.truncate()).round(6)
    totalsecs = (dec * 3600).round(6)
    mins = (totalsecs / 60).truncate()
    secs = (((totalsecs / 60) - (totalsecs / 60).truncate()) * 60).round(2)
    array = [deg, mins, secs]
end

DMS(arg1)
bearingarray = array
```

If you ran the second block of code however, you would end up with an array of [1, 2, 3].

My expectation was that I would get that exact same values in the array, but under the different name.

What has gone wrong? What should I do to fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your code has all sorts of problems that strongly suggest you might want to use a different approach to learning both Ruby and its integration into Sketchup.  Is there possibly a specific Ruby/Sketchup forum or personal coach you might be able to use?

Comment: Again, this is hardy the place for this type of thing, but just as a favor, I'll point out a few things:  You shouldn't use a local variable in your method definition.  It makes no sense.  ```def DMS(arg1)``` should probably be something like ```def DMS(any_arg)``` or ```def DMS(num).  You're not defining a method based on a local variable.  You're defining a method that can be used with ANY valid value.  That's why its useful.  Also, ```truncate``` doesn't need the parentheses if you're not using an argument, and there's no reason to define ```array``` inside your method.

Comment: BTW, I recommend not starting a method name with an upper case letter. It works in your case, because you require a parameter, but say you want to change the definition to make the parameter optional. You can't call a parameterless method, where the name starts with an upper case letter, because the parser would think that it is the name of a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second code block is wrong, if you run it you get `undefined local variable or method array for main:Object`.

You are probably running the code in an interactive session and you have defined `array` before, take into account `array` is local to `DMS` function.

I would say what you want is to do

```
arg1 = 45.525123

def DMS(arg1)
  angle = arg1
  deg = angle.truncate()
  dec = (angle - angle.truncate()).round(6)
  totalsecs = (dec * 3600).round(6)
  mins = (totalsecs / 60).truncate()
  secs = (((totalsecs / 60) - (totalsecs / 60).truncate()) * 60).round(2)
  array = [deg, mins, secs]
end


bearingarray = DMS(arg1)
```

Assigning the output of `DMS` to `bearingarray`

Comment: May I suggest to remove the meaningless assignment to the variable `array` inside the `DMS` method? You just create a local variable and throw it away immediately. Of course this already exists in the OPs original code, but IMO, it does not help the OP to repeat something which is already badly designed from the onset.

Comment: Agree with @user1934428.  In addition, if it were me it would probably be ```def DMS(angle)``` and I would completely delete ```angle = arg1```...and that's just for starters.

Comment: Agree, the code can be improved in many ways, I just copy/pasted the definition so it is clear what needs to be changed in order to answer the original question